# How to show recent post in the main domain from subdomain blog

Tags: wordpress

need to show the recent post from my subdomain to my main domain frontend. I am using below code, but its picking only main domain recent post. any help to fetch subdomain recent post ?

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<?php wp_get_archives('title_li=&type=postbypost&limit=10'); ?>` its also displaying the same results. any more helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2:

So it turns out, that you are not running both sites from the same WordPress installation(otherwise referred to as a WordPress Network). Here is what I can suggest that you use in this case.

Put this code in the main site's `functions.php`:

```
/**
* this function retrieves the requested part of the main site
* ok, well basically can be from any site, depending on the $url param, as long as it has the proper function that will display the requested content
* @param $url - the url of the site
* @param $key - part of the name of the function that will display the content
* @param $add_qs - any additional query string that will be appended, use "&params=param1,param2,param3" to pass "param1", "param2" and "param3"
* to the loading function
*/
function get_main_site_part($url, $key, $add_qs = '') {

    // cache the result, so we don't make a request with each page load
    $cache = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/main_site_' . $key . '.txt';
    $cache_lifetime = 300;

    // just to make sure - try to remove the trailing slash in the $url
    $url = untrailingslashit($url);
    $uri = $url . '/?including_template_part=1&load_part=' . $key . $add_qs;

    # reload the cache on every 5 minutes
    if (!file_exists($cache) || time() - filemtime($cache) > $cache_lifetime) {
        $main_site_html = wp_remote_get($uri);
        if (is_a($main_site_html, 'WP_Error')) {
            //print_r($main_site_html);
            //exit('error! ');
            return;
        }

        $fp = fopen($cache, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $main_site_html);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $main_site_html = file_get_contents($cache);
    }

    return $main_site_html;
}
```

Now put this function in your sub-domain's `functions.php`:

```
/* HTML LOADING HOOK - For loading content from one site to another - best application in multisite */
function print_requested_template_part() {
    // Respond only to requests from the same address... 
    if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['including_template_part']) && isset($_GET['load_part']) && $_GET['load_part'] != '' ) {
        $part = $_GET['load_part'];
        $func = 'render_' . str_replace('-', '_', $part); // if you have declared a function called "render_footer_include", then "?load_part=footer_include"
        if ( function_exists($func) ) {
            // Allow for passing parameters to the function
            if ( isset($_GET['params']) ) {
                $params = $_GET['params'];
                $params = ( strpos($params, ',') !== false )? explode(',', $params) : array($params);
                call_user_func_array($func, $params);
            } else {
                call_user_func($func);
            }
        }
        exit; // if we don't exit here, a whole page will be printed => bad! it's better to have empty footer than a footer with the whole main site...
    }
}
add_action('init', 'print_requested_template_part', 1);

function render_my_recent_posts( $numberposts = 5 ) { ?>
    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        }
    ?>
    </ul><?php
}
```

Then in your main site call this function, where you want your recent posts to appear:

```
echo get_main_site_part( 'http://questions.admissiontimes.com/', 'my_recent_posts', '&params=5' )
```

EDIT 1:

Using the sample code that you have in your question, combined with my solution from below, here is what the final code will look like:

```
<?php 
switch_to_blog( 2 ); // Switch to the blog that you want to pull posts from. You can see the ID when you edit a site through the Network Admin - the URL will look something like "http://example.com/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=2" - you need the value of "id", in this case "2" ?>
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php restore_current_blog(); // Restore the current blog ?>
```

Now, you just put that code wherever you had your original code and everything should be working properly.

---

You need to switch to the blog in question, using the [`switch_to_blog($blog_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) function, where `$blog_id` is the ID of the blog(sub-site) in question.

Then do your normal get_posts/or equivalent/ function and display/store the posts in the way you want.

Once you're done with that, just call [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog) and that's it.

Comment: I did not understand really from where to start up actually, can you please summarize a bit more ? Thankyou

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of what the final code should look like.

Comment: Grt Grt Just Grt @Nikola. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need to defines this functions as well ? Switch_to_blog()  ?? its shows its undefined functions--

Comment: You are using this code inside of a WordPress multisite(network) installation, right? If so, you **should** have those functions defined already. If you don't, there is something wrong with your installation.

Comment: See, i have a main domain, like http://admissiontimes.com/, then a http://questions.admissiontimes.com, need to show the recent post which comes on right side of subdomain on my main domain homepage. its a widget through its showing the latest post. how i can show these post of subdomain to main domain home page ? I hope this time its sounds properly :)

Comment: both domain are in wordpress,

Comment: I updated my answer again, and sure we can move that to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19755/discussion-between-nikita-chopra-and-nikola-ivanov-nikolov)