# How to show recent posts on the main domain from a subdomain blog as well

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I got 2 separate installations of WordPress, one on the main site and other on the sub-domain. Is there a possibility of showing posts from sub-domain on the main site, along with the articles of the main site. Like, every alternate article displayed, be from the sub-domain irrespective of the date published.

I read this article, but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted:
[How to show recent post in the main domain from subdomain blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451524/how-to-show-recent-post-in-the-main-domain-from-subdomain-blog)

Here are the functions.php, index.php and single.php files of the theme I'm using:

1. Functions.php http://pastebin.com/s3tfdnB2
2. Index.php http://pastebin.com/nxtMZzLq
3. Single.php http://pastebin.com/sgpfvtVe

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code

Comment: But, please, don't include unnecessary code. See http://sscce.org . Anyway, this is too broad, there are multiple solutions. One is reading the RSS feed.

Comment: @Paddyd which code do you want me to include? I added 3 php files in the questions, which are not edited yet.

Comment: @BhanuAhluwalia I mean include the relevant code in the question itself, rather than links to the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about access the database of the subdomain in your main domain and query the recent posts there.

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select recent posts");
echo "<ul>";
   foreach ($rows as $obj) :
      //display data here
   endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

[see more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)

**NOTE:** This isn't a perfect solution if you've enabled Wordpress network for your subdomain.